# search all files for string in directory, java.nio

Tags: java, string, full-text-search

I want to search a string in all files in a particular directory. Want to know if there is any way to do so using java.nio package. Basically i am going to use this feature in the web application( i am strictly against doing it, but requirement is requirement). There is a pathSearch in nio but it only searches for particular pattern. And also the traditional way to open an file and search line by line, but doing this takes a bit of time and also the resources.

Any Help on this is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to open and search all files when you get the requested string, for performance reasons, you'll need an index. I'd suggest you have a look at Lucene (https://lucene.apache.org/core/), which is a full text engine in Java. You could index all your documents with it and run the query using its query syntax, the performance is very good. Of course then you'll have to manage when to update the index (maybe checking the last modified dates of all files, etc).

Comment: i think thats really a good option, the only caveat i see in this is i need to install lucene, which is still doable. Thanks Man